# Issue with constraints imposed by Spring's PropertyOverrideConfigurer class

Tags: spring, properties-file

I am experiencing **issues with configuration and properties management** with my app.

Basically I have a number of properties files each containing a number of properties (key/value).

On the other hand my app **uses a number of Spring environment profiles** ("dev", "test", etc).

Most of those properties are the same for all of the app's profiles but for some do differ.

The idea is to have **all properties defined in one place** and **having each profile override those properties according to the profile requirements**. And that's where I am having issues...

I have tried to have a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as a base source (not tied to any specific profile) of properties to be overridden and then a number of `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` each tied to a specific profile that would override the base source.

Here is my config as of now:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfigurerConfiguration {

    static class defaultConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:META-INF/props/*.properties"));
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }
    }

    @Profile(Profiles.DEV)
    static class devConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public static PropertyOverrideConfigurer propertyOverrideConfigurer() throws IOException {
            PropertyOverrideConfigurer propertyOverrideConfigurer = new PropertyOverrideConfigurer();
            propertyOverrideConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(Boolean.TRUE);
            propertyOverrideConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:META-INF/props/dev/*.properties"));
            return propertyOverrideConfigurer;
        }
    }

    @Profile(Profiles.TEST)
    static class testConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:META-INF/props/*.properties"));
            Properties localProperties = new Properties();
            localProperties.setProperty("google_api.key", "TEST-API-KEY");
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(localProperties);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocalOverride(Boolean.TRUE);
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }

        @Bean
        public static PropertyOverrideConfigurer propertyOverrideConfigurer() throws IOException {
            PropertyOverrideConfigurer propertyOverrideConfigurer = new PropertyOverrideConfigurer();
            propertyOverrideConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(Boolean.TRUE);
            propertyOverrideConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:META-INF/props/test/*.properties"));
            return propertyOverrideConfigurer;
        }
    }
    ...
```

Notice how I had to redefine a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` specifically for the test profile and use the local override. This is only a temporary hack and one that I would like to get rid of...

The issues I therefore have are the following:

- I can't have an arbitrary key that will be taken into account and override that in the base `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. It seems that it has to follow a `beanName.property` pattern or I have to use `setIgnoreInvalidKeys` but then the arbitrary keys will not be taken into account. e.g. I can't have a property such as `application.url=http://localhost:8080/myApp` and use it in a @Component...
- What is more the issue can also occurs with something like the jpa properties map:

See following config:

```
entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(propertiesMap());

private Map<String, String> propertiesMap() {
        Map<String, String> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", ???);
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.format_sql", ???);
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", ???);
        return propertiesMap;
    }
```

The constraint imposed by the override configurer does not seem to allow for overriding properties such as `hibernate.format_sql`, etc...

My question is then: how can I use the `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` to suit my application requirements (see above). Or is there another solution to override the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`?

**edit 1**:

I have modified my configuration and I am having new issues at context startup:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/classpath*:META-INF/props/dev/app-config.properties]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:323)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:227)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:241)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:152)
    ... 18 more
```

Here is my class after I modified it:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name = "default-configuration", value = { "classpath*:META-INF/props/app-config.properties", "classpath*:META-INF/props/database.properties",
        "classpath*:META-INF/props/email.properties" })
public class PropertyConfigurerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(Boolean.TRUE);
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile(Profiles.DEV)
    @PropertySource(name = "dev-configuration", value = { "classpath*:META-INF/props/dev/app-config.properties", "classpath*:META-INF/props/dev/database.properties",
            "classpath*:META-INF/props/dev/email.properties" })
    public static class DevConfiguration {
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile(Profiles.TEST)
    @PropertySource(name = "test-configuration", value = { "classpath*:META-INF/props/test/app-config.properties", "classpath*:META-INF/props/test/database.properties" })
    public static class TestConfiguration {
    }

}
```

**edit 2**: I sorted the issue described in edit 1 by changing all `classpath*:xx` to `classpath:xx`. However I noticed that the dev property source does not override the  default one i.e. keys from the default PropertySource are used whereas the same keys exist in the dev PropertySource...

Comment: It seems spring does not allow wildcards such as `*.properties` nor `classpath*:` when using the @PropertySource annotation.

Comment: Regarding edit2, try adding another internal `@Configuration` class and add it after the `@Configuration` classes annotated with `@Profile`. (See my modified answer).

Comment: I tried your modified answer (even moved the default configuration to the top so that the dev would override the default one) and it still does not work (it picks up only the default configuration). Here is how I've activated the profile `spring.profiles.active=dev`...

Comment: I would assume the ordering to be maintained, but that might differ on jdk/platform combo. I suggest going with the `ApplicationContextInitializer` solution, more flexible and powerful and you can guarantee the order of your files.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marten. I might have to go for the context initializer then... I am surprised to see that it is so difficult for one property source to override another with the same keys. :-( Basically that's just what I wanted to achieve...

Comment: Depends on what you find difficult. Trying to get the ordering right with a `@PropertySource` can be a pain. With the `ApplicationContextInitializer` you have guarantees which you don't really have with `@PropertySource` annotations.

Comment: I agree. I have been through a nightmare trying one configurer and its properties to override another...

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it looks to complex what you do. Why not simply add a `@PropertySource` annotation for each profile? Including a default one.

```
@Configuration

public class PropertyConfigurerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile(Profiles.DEV)
    @PropertySource(name="dev-configuration", value="classpath*:META-INF/props/dev/*.properties")
    public static class DevConfiguration{}

    @Configuration
    @Profile(Profiles.TEST)
    @PropertySource(name="test-configuration", value="classpath*:META-INF/props/test/*.properties")
    public static class DevConfiguration{}

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(name="default-configuration", value="classpath*:META-INF/props/*.properties")
    public static class DefaultConfiguration() {}
}
```

This will always load the default and add the others depending on the profile, which should override properties from the default configuration.

Another solution, would be to create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which adds the `PropertySource` in its `initialize` method.

```
public class MyInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    private static String DEFAULT_CONFIG_LOCATION= "classpath*:META-INF/props/*.properties";

    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        MutablePropertySources mps = env.getPropertySources();
        String[] profiles = env.getActiveProfiles();
        for (String profile : profiles) {
            String location = "classpath*:META-INF/props/"+profile+"/*.properties";
            Resource[] resources = applicationContext.getResources(location);
            if (resources != null) {
                for (Resource res: resources) {
                    mps.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource(res));
                }
            }
        }

        // Load defaults as last
        Resource[] resources = applicationContext.getResources(DEFAULT_CONFIG_LOCATION);
            if (resources != null) {
                for (Resource res: resources) {
                    mps.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource(res));
                }
            }
    }
}
```

You can then register this in your web.xml as a `globalInitializerClasses` which will apply it to all `ApplicationContext`s that are created within this application. This also means that you can remove the `@PropertySource` annotations and specialized configurations. Advantage of this is that if you create a new profile, you don't have to add another `@Configuration` class to load the resources.

If you want to replace the hibernate properties you will have to utilize the `Environment` to add the properties in the first place.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

private Map<String, String> propertiesMap() {
    Map<String, String> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
    propertiesMap.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    propertiesMap.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    propertiesMap.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
    propertiesMap.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
    propertiesMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql", Boolean.class, false));
    propertiesMap.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql", Boolean.class, false));
    propertiesMap.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", env.getProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", Boolean.class, false));
    return propertiesMap;
}
```

This will get the property from the `Environment` and thus from the configured `PropertySource`s and if not found will use a default `false` in this case.

Comment: Hi Marten. Looks very neat. One point I am not sure about: what is the **name** attribute of the @PropertySource annotation used for? I only found this in the doc: *Indicate the name of this property source. If omitted, a name will be generated based on the description of the underlying resource.* Can you please tell me what  it is for?

Comment: It is used to register the property source (you can omit it if you want). But I find it helpful with debugging/logging as the name is also printed to show in which `PropertySource` a property value was found.

Comment: I am going to try all of that when I return to my dev machine tonight!! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Marten. I have edited my post. Also one little point you forgot to mention is that the @PropertySource annotation does not allow wildcards.

Comment: You are right, I was hoping that there was support for that. Just looked at the sources and it isn't.